# Interleave 2 strings alternatively in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm making a C program that interchanges all the alphabets when given 2 strings. For example if it's given "abc" and "123", it should give the output "a1b2c3". The problem I'm having is when I'm accessing the elements in the array. The code doesn't run and gives an error. Here's my code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char a[80];
    char b[80];
    char l[120];
    char f[120];
    strcpy(a, "abc");
    strcpy(f, "");
    strcpy(l, "abc");
    strcpy(b,"123");
    strcat(a,b);
    int pop;
    pop = sizeof(a);
    int j;
    int k;
    k=0;

    for (j=0;j<pop;j++)
    { 
        if (j%2==0 ) {
            strcat(f,l[k]);
        } 
        else{
            strcat(f,b[k]);
            k++;
        }
    }
    printf("String is %s ",f);
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: You should use `strlen` instead of `sizeof`.

Comment: I think you mean "interleave" rather than "interchange".

Comment: "The code doesn't run and gives an error". What error are you getting? What is the expected output, and what is the actual output?

Comment: It all looks completerly illogical. Go back and think it over again. BTW, you cannot use `strcat` to append a single character.

Comment: @haccks: I wouldn't say that's a mere nitpick; it's an outright bug.

Comment: @MOehm; Hahaha... yes, agreed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    pop = sizeof(a);
```

Will not return the size of the content of a but the size of the array.  As mentioned by @hacks you should use 'strlen'.

Also don't use strcpy to initialise a string or strcat to append characters, to initialise the string:

```
    f[0] = '\0';
```

To append:

```
    int d = 0;
    f[d] = '\0';
    pop = strlen(a);    
    for( j=0; j<pop; j++) {
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
            f[d++] = l[k];
        } else {
            f[d++] = b[k++];
        }
    }
```

Calling strcat to append 1 byte is not very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with concatenation. try this to append onto the string

```
strncat(f, &l[k],1);
```

check the loop below, it should work fine

```
pop = strlen(a);//change this
for (j = 0; j < pop; j++)
{
    if (j % 2 == 0) {
        strncat(f, &l[k],1);  
    }
    else {
        strncat(f, &b[k],1);
        k++;
    }
}
printf("String is %s ", f);
```

Outputs:

```
a1b2c3
```

cheers

Comment: The OP wants to append a single character. Your code will add the whole string starting with `a[k]`. If you build a string character-wise, don't use `strcat`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
pop = strlen(a)
```

And change the for loop to

```
for (j = 1; j <= pop; j++)
{
    if (j % 2 == 0) {
        strcat(f, l[k]);
        k++;
    }
    else {
        strcat(f, b[k]);
    }
}
printf("String is %s ", f);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply assign the characters rather than using concatention:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

int main()
{
char a[80];
char b[80];
char l[120];
char f[120];
strcpy(a, "abc");
strcpy(f, "");
strcpy(l, "abc");
strcpy(b,"123");
strcat(a,b);
int pop;
pop= strlen(a);

int j,k=0;

int index = 0;
for (j=0;j<pop;j++)
{
    if (j%2==0 ) {
        f[index++] = l[k];
       // printf("%s\n",f);
    }
    else{
        f[index++] = b[k];
        k++;
    }
}
f[index] = '\0';
printf("String is %s ",f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do things the easy way.Try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[80];
    char b[80];
    char l[120];
    strcpy_s(a, sizeof(a), "abc");
    strcpy_s(b, sizeof(b), "123");
    int pop;
    pop = strlen(a);
    int i, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < pop * 2; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            l[i] = a[j];
        }
        else {
            l[i] = b[j++];
        }
    }
    l[i] = '\0';
    printf("String is %s ", l);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You incorrectly use strcat as it simply appends `'\0'` each time you call it and you experience *buffer overflow*, you write past the end of the array. Assign characters instead of this and double check you access valid and proper indices. Assert resulting string is null terminated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char even[4];
    char odd[4];
    char res[7];
    strcpy(even, "abc");
    strcpy(odd,"123");
    int pop;
    printf("even %s\n", even);
    printf("odd %s\n", odd);
    pop = sizeof(res)-1;
    int j;

    for (j=0; j<pop; ++j)
    { 
       if (j%2 == 0 ) {
            res[j] = even[j/2];
        } 
        else{
            res[j] = odd[(j-1)/2];
        }
    }
    res[j] = '\0';
    printf("String is %s",res);
}
```

https://ideone.com/1aYupy

Answer (score 1):

You've already gotten enough answers. Some of them and the commenst point out your errors:

- When you build strings character by character, don't use `strcat`. Assign the chars to the `char` array manually. make sure that you don't overflow the buffer and don't forget the null character at the end.
- `sizeof` will not give you the length of a string. `strlen` from `<strings.h>` will do that, but the string must be properly null-terminated for it to work. In fact, you can use `str[i] != '\0'` in a loop to check whether you are past the null terminator or not.
- Take care of the input. For example, you have fourstrings in your code, but you really just need three: The two source strings that you want to interleave and the result string. In your code, the source strings have at most 80  characters. The result string has at most 120 characters. When the source strings are longer than 60 characters, your buffers will overflow.
- What should happen when the source strings have different lengths? Do you want to stop interleaving when the shorter string has run out? Do you just want to append the rest of the longer string after interleaving? That are things that you should think about and care for. In your code, the first string must be shorter than the second, but you don't enforce that.

Here's a solution that uses a simple method:

- As long as there are still characters inboth source strings, take the first characters from both strings and put them into the result string.
- After that, append the rest of the longerstring to the string.

Note that the code takes care not to overflow the buffer and assures that the string is terminated witha null, even when it is cut short.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

size_t interleave(char *buf, size_t max, const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    size_t i = 0;           // index into s1
    size_t j = 0;           // index into s2
    size_t k = 0;           // index into buf

    while (s1[i] && s2[j] && k + 1 < max) {
        buf[k++] = s1[i++];
        if (k + 1 < max) buf[k++] = s2[j++];
    }
    while (s1[i] && k + 1 < max) buf[k++] = s1[i++];
    while (s2[j] && k + 1 < max) buf[k++] = s2[j++];

    buf[k] = '\0';
    return k;
}

int main()
{
    char buf[32];

    interleave(buf, sizeof(buf), "abcdefg", "123");
    puts(buf);

    return 0;
}
```